# Javascript function name followed by multiline string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Today I noticed that if you put a string after a function name you get something odd returned:

```js
function func(param) { console.log(param) }
func`wizbang`; // ['wizbang', raw: Array(1)]
```

What am I looking at here? I can't seem to assign it to a variable either so I'm very confused at what I stumbled upon. Does this language feature have an official name I can look up more info?

Comment: It's a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)